# Wrap single line with multiple TextViews in a RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a custom row for a listview that contains four TextViews.

Here is a screenshot of the layout I am creating:

[image: problem]

The reason for multiple TextView is because I need to use different styles on each textview. Bold Name for example.

Here is the XML layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgPhoto"
        android:src="@color/Red"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_margin="10dp" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgPhoto"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Name"
            android:id="@+id/txtName"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="viewed a promotion by"
            android:id="@+id/txtAction"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txtName" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Dominos Pizza"
            android:id="@+id/txtMerchant"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txtAction" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="14 seconds ago"
            android:id="@+id/txtAgo"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txtMerchant" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is a screenshot of what I am trying to achieve:

[image: correct]

The question is how do I wrap the TextViews so that it fits inside the RelativeLayout just like in Picture 2? Or is there any other alternative I can use to achieve what I am looking for here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's possible through HTML code. You should be use to CSS for the wrap the text and then set into the view.

Comment: Good idea. I'm trying it out.

Answer (score 1):

Use only one TextView and change the style with html. Example:

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<h2>This</h2><br><p>is an example.</p>"));
```